# Displaying image alone at the end of section

Tags: graphics, page-breaking

I'm working on a project, and I'm having trouble right at this point:

```
\section{Chapter3}
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
   
   \begin{figure}
      ...
   \end{figure}
   \newpage

\section{Chapter4}
```

As it can be seen, I have a chapter, Chapter3, with a lot of text and with an image right at the end of it. This image must be there, I cannot put it a couple paragraphs earlier or something else, it has to be right at the end of the chapter. It turns out that the text of this chapter ends, when displayed, right at the end of one page, so the image should be displayed alone in the following page and in the next one, the next chapter should begin to be displayed. The issue is that this does not occur, but actually the image is displayed on the following page among with Chapter4, right above it, with no page break. It drives me mad to watch it like this:

[image]

I tried using [!] in the \begin{figure} and nothing; the commands \newpage and \pagebreak are doing nothing for me. I found a very rudimentary solution, which is to add two paragraphs of text in color white to force the page break, but I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution, so my advisor don't freak out about the random "lorem impsum" text at the end of that chapter.

Comment: Why are you using `\section` to write a chapter? What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: If the figure must go *right there*, and it fits, don't use a float.  Use `\includegraphics` directly, and if it needs a caption, use `\captionof` (`caption` package).

Comment: use `\clearpage` not `\newpage` to stop floats going past

Comment: You could use `\begin{figure}[hbp]…\end{figure}\clearpage`. The options prevent placing the figure at the top of the page and the `\clearpage` forces the output of the figure.